# Use couchbase as storage for Keycloak

Tags: nosql, couchbase, keycloak

Is there any guide to use couchbase or NoSQL as the database layer for  Keycloak?

My research indicates that Keycloak only has support for RDBMS. MongoDB was supported once but was removed.